# Can packages be chosen with vsctool or only --packages-up-to?

Tags: ros, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Colcon allows to limit the building of a workspace by specifying `--packages-up-to` .  However I am wondering if there's a way to limit `vsctool` from downloading all packages in a repository.

For example: In the Autoware Universe repo, under the perception directory, there's a number of [packages](https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.universe/tree/main/perception).  By specifying it in the `.repos` file:

```
universe/autoware.universe:
    type: git
    url: https://github.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.universe.git
    version: main
```

vsctool will bring in all directories under this repository.

Assuming we are only interested in the `traffic_light_classifier` (and its dependencies), is there a way to specify this in the `.repos` file, or is `--packages-up-to` the only viable option?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401264/can-packages-be-chosen-with-vsctool-or--only---packages-up-to?/) by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2022-05-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is not something `vcstool` supports.

`vcstool` has one responsibility, and that's cloning/downloading repositories/archives listed in a `.repos` file (in addition to some other convenience methods having to do with interacting with all those cloned/downloaded repositories).

It doesn't know anything about packages, about ROS, workspaces, or anything like that.

It's purely a convenience tool around `git`, `svn` and some other VCS tools.

---

Edit: having written that, there is an issue asking for this functionality: [dirk-thomas/vcstool#218](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool/issues/218), and an open PR which proposes to add this functionality: [dirk-thomas/vcstool#219](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool/pull/219).

Note that even with the PR merged, `vcstool` would still not know anything about *packages*. The PR only adds the ability to selectively checkout *directories*. There is no guarantee, nor requirement, that each directory only contains a single package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2